# Spring @RequestPart multipart/mixed Object errors

Tags: spring, http-post, content-type, multipart, mixed

I am attempting to upload a file with additional parameters using RequestParts.  I have the file uploading correctly; however, when I try and add in the additional parameters I get an error in response.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/cases/{caseId}/file", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Success uploadFile(
        @RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart(value="fileParameters") FileParameters fileParameters) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
```

I have tried to POST to this 2 different ways with different errors:

1)

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myFile"
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileParameters"

{"filePassword":"testPassword", "configuration":{}, "target":null}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

this errors with:

```
The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method. See 'supportedMediaTypes' in 'additionalInfo' for a list of supported types
```

2)

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myFile"
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileParamters[filePassword]"

testPassword
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileParamters[configuration]"

{}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileParamters[target]"

null
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

which returns the following error:

```
"rootExceptionClass": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
"rootExceptionMessage": "Required request part 'keyParameters' is not present."
```

I'm assuming the first approach is the correct one; however, the application does support JSON, so I'm not sure what I am missing configuration wise.  Is there something I have to add to the request for this to work correctly, or am I missing something in a message converter.

Note: Not sure this matters but I am using Postman to test the endpoint.

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? I've been stuck with the same problem too. I've looked at many solutions but none seem to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did.  I just wound up passing the request body as a json string in a request param and using jackson to get it into the object I need. Far from ideal.

Comment: Old question and I am not sure if it is the issue but still gonna leave a comment. Your "fileParameters" is being posted as form-data. Maybe try posting as application/json

Answer (score 0):

add

> Content-Type: application/json;

under the line of

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileParameters"

to explicit how to resolve your parameters

see spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue with you! I changed the @RequestPart to @Multipart, the issue was fixed. hope it can help for you!